# Rails ActiveRecord find a table attribute's value given conditions in 2 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have 2 tables:

1. A conversations table that contains a list of conversations with their IDs (and two users ids associated to each ('recipient_id' and 'sender_id').
2. A messages table that contains messages associated to one of the existing conversations. Every instance of Message includes a boolean attribute 'read' (defaults false) intended to show if there are any unread messages in a conversation.

So Conversation has_many :messages and Message belongs_to :conversation

My objective is to check if the current_user has any unread messages (in any of his existing conversations) to display a general alert.
So far I've managed to display an alert for each conversation but I'm struggling to find an efficient way to implement a general one.

My original approach was to:

1. Find the last message in each of the current user's conversations.
2. Evaluate if each of those last messages were sent by the current user AND if read == false.
3. Return true if any of those last messages met these condition.

This translated into the following code:

```
  @conversations = current_user.conversations
  @unread = []
  if @conversations.exists?

      @conversations.each do |conversation|
        if conversation.messages.exists?
          if conversation.messages.last.user_id != current_user.id && conversation.messages.last.read == false
            @unread << true
          end
        end
      end
  end

  @unread.include?(true)
end
```

I'm quite new coding but it seems a pretty inefficient method having to loop through all current_users conversations and creating an array to check if there's any 'true' value on it.

I'd loop through the messages themselves but an instance only has the user_id of the sender so if I don't link it with the Conversation model there's no way to know if a message was sent to him.

Could you help with an efficient way to achieve this with a more appropriate Active Record query or a better approach.

By the way, not sure if matters but I'm using postgresql in my dev environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `conversation` ids for `current_user` by something like:

```
conv_ids = current_user.conversations.pluck(:id)
```

The do a query to get the message count meeting your required criteria like:

```
unread_count = Message.where(convsersation_id: conv_ids, read: false).where.not(user_id: current_user.id).count
```

if `unread_count > 0` then you can show alert

I am assuming that all messages gets a `read :true` value once read so this query will return true even if any other message other that the last message in conversation has `read :false`.

PS: I have not tested the queries, so check it and do adjustments if necessary.And if I am missing anything here then ask that in comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sajan. It makes sense. Let me give it a try and think about it and go back to you as soon I have news.